# Invalid Token. Not accepting integers that start with 0

Tags: python, syntax-error, check-digit

So I'm trying to make a check digit function, and embarrassingly, I've already run into a snag early on that I've been trying to search the problem for, but most of the explanations I've run into are unfortunately beyond my comprehension. I'm hoping someone could give me a specific run-down as to what my problem is right now

```
mam = []

def check_digit():
    a = int(input("Please enter your 10 digit book number"))
    b = str(a)
    for c in b:
        mam.append(c)
        print(c)

check_digit()
```

Sorry about no set names for variables, I prefer coding this way even if it eventually gets awkward for others to read. Well anyway, every time I write in an integer which starts with 0, the Syntax error "Invalid token" appears and I don't know how to solve it. Could anyone help me? I would be grateful

**Fixed.** I really need to update Python, I'm running 2.7 at the moment.

raw_input solved the issue

Comment: `b` would not be defined. It's local to the `check_digit()` function

Comment: Maybe your indentation is wrong? The for loop should belong to the check_digit function.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake when I copied it into stack overflow. It's fixed now.

Comment: Can you post the whole error traceback? So we can see in which line the error happens.

Comment: Code however you want, but if you're going to ask others to read your code and help you, it would be courteous to use more descriptive variable names. In this case it doesn't matter so much, but you'll be happier in the long run if you break the habit now.

Comment: I don't get an error: if I type in `0123456789` as input, it returns this :  `123456789`

Comment: Note that when you cast a string as an int, leading zeroes are dropped. (e.g. `str(int("001"))` returns `"1"`.) Could be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cast `a` as an int, but never use it as an int. Try looping through the input string directly.

```
mam = []

def check_digit():
    a = raw_input("Please enter your 10 digit book number")
    for c in a:
        mam.append(c)
        print(c)

check_digit()
```

Other answers' explanations about the source of the problem make sense to me. This should fix the problem, since you never need to interpret your input as an integer at all.

Comment: @PearseTraynor my mistake, in python2.7 you should use `raw_input`. This will cause the interpreter to take input as a string in all cases, as opposed to `input`, which tries to deduce the input type. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in python, numbers starting with `0` are in octal base, the 'invalid token' error you're getting must be on a digit greater than 7, which is illegal in a base 8 number. Try using `raw_input()` instead of `input()` so that the value won't be evaluated as a number.

Comment: The code works though, if I input ``09``, w/o throwing an exception.

Comment: @MikeScotty incorrect, it fails for `09` as input with the same error 'invalid token' (python 2.7)

Comment: well, it does not fail on Python 3.4, OP never specified the python version, but it might as well be 2.7

Comment: raw_input() on Py2 is the same as input() on Py3.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, non-decimal numbers start with '0'. A decimal number cannot start with a '0'. Old-style octal numbers used to start with a '0', so '010' would be 8 in Python 2. Hex numbers started with '0x' and still do in Python 3. In Python 3, octal numbers now start with '0o'.
You're throwing the error because you're inputting a string and then running int() on it.  Don't do that. You can just check if the inputted string is all digits instead and make sure it's the right length.
Or, if you have your heart set on checking for a conversion to *int* as a decimal, you should strip off the leading zeros with `value.lstrip('0')` before the conversion.

Alternatively, you can just input the mam and then check `if mam.isdigit():`...
The `.isdigit()` method checks if the string consists only of numerical digits. This should be what you're looking for.

Comment: So use type() and len() instead of a list? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @PearseTraynor -
   acctnum = input(...; if acctnum.isdigit(): do it

Comment: @PearseTraynor - I'd say the combo of len() and .isdigit() should do quite nicely. :)

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem of `str` versus `int` with me:

```
mam = []

def check_digit():
    a = str(input("Please enter your 10 digit book number: "))
    [mam.append(int(inputted)) for inputted in a]
    print(mam)

check_digit()
print(mam[0] + mam[1])
print(type(mam[0]))
```

input:

```
Please enter your 10 digit book number: 0123456789
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1
<class 'int'>
```